# Why is it OK to jump into the scope of an object of scalar type w/o an initializer?

Tags: c++, goto

When I'm reading the C++ standard, it seems that the following code is perfectly fine according to the standard.

```
int main() {
   goto lol;
   {
      int x;
lol:
      cout << x << endl;
   }
}

// OK
```

> [n3290: 6.7/3]: It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a
>   way that bypasses declarations with initialization. A program that
>   jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is
>   not in scope to a point where it is in scope is ill-formed **unless the
>   variable has scalar type**, class type with a trivial default
>   constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of
>   these types, or an array of one of the preceding types **and is declared
>   without an initializer**.

Why should it work? Isn't it still dangerous to jump over its definition and use undefined `x`? And why should the existence of an initializer make any difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd use an uninitialized `x` anyways, since `int x;` is as uninitialized as it's going to get. The existence of an initializer makes of course a difference, because you'd be skipping it. `int x = 5;` for example initializes `x`, so it would make a difference if you jumped over it or not.

Comment: But the problem is, regardless there is an initializer, x is not defined because its definition is bypassed anyway. Isn't it?

Comment: @EricZ: The definition still occurs. `goto` is a runtime thing, it only skips runtime behavior, like initialization.

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't it still dangerous to jump over its definition and use uninitialized `x`?

But `x` would be uninitialized anyway, because it was declared without an initializer! So the `goto` might be skipping over assignment statements that set (sort-of-initialize) `x`, but it's not surprising that `goto` can skip over assignment statements; and the declaration itself doesn't actually *do* anything unless there's an initializer.

Comment: +1 *the declaration itself doesn't actually do anything*. That's the key point. Without an initializer, no code is generated. The rules ensure that you're not actually skipping over any code.

Comment: @Ernest, I'm curious how x is defined because its definition is passed away?

Comment: Imagine that a free processor register is designated to hold `x`. That's just bookkeeping in the compiler; there's nothing physically in the generated code that says "Register 17 is now `x`." Now, if `x` were initialized, we'd have code to set the register's value -- but as we said, there's none of that.

Comment: @Ernest, Now it makes sense to me, thanks for your comments;)