# Why is jumping across variable definitions (with goto) allowed?

Tags: c++, variables

I am confused with variable definition, when playing with `goto` and `switch` statements. 
The below code were accepted by compiler:

```
goto label0;
int j; // skipped by "goto"

label0:
j = 3;
```

My questions are:

1. Since the definition of `int j;` is skipped, how will the program create object `j` and later assign value to it in `j = 3` ?
2. Is the code between `goto` and `label` **compiled**?
3. Is the code between `goto` and `label` **executed**? (at run-time)
4. Does variable definition happen at compile-time(or more proper term) or run-time?

(I ask this as a new question focusing more on the relative order of variable definition and compilation and execution. )

Comment: Don't use `goto` in 1st place :P ...

Comment: IIRC, this is undefined behavior. I don't remember for sure and don't have a standard quote ready, though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, how about `switch`. Can we dodge that also?

Comment: *A
program that jumps from a point where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a
point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has scalar type, class type with a trivial default
constructor and a trivial destructor, a cv-qualified version of one of these types, or an array of one of the
preceding types and is declared without an initializer (8.5).* Didn't see anything about using that variable.

Comment: @chris An int is a scalar (right?) so this section would imply the OP's code is well formed.

Comment: _'Can we dodge that also?'_ Yeah, we can! Have a look at this recently asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24343724/does-a-variable-defined-inside-a-switch-case-persists-its-value

Comment: @DavidGrayson, Actually, it would not (alone) AFAICT because nothing is said about using the variable that comes into scope. Maybe it's implied to be ok to use. I don't know. To answer the question, yes, `int` is a scalar.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I doubt the ostrich style is the right way to go :P

Comment: @aruisdante, This is different. That question violates the "declared without an initializer" part.

Comment: @user3701346 _'I doubt the ostrich style is the right way to go ...'_ Didn't mean to recommend it, but pointing out it's UB as well, as stated there!!

Comment: Remember: C++ (and C) accept *many* programs which are not well-defined.. just because it compiled without errors - remember to enable/check warnings - does not mean it is "legitimate".

Comment: @chris Yes, but the answers explain both cases. As does the various answers/duplicates linked in the question from πάντα ῥεῖ

Comment: @aruisdante, Oh, you're right. The second one does. And the other link was funny to see because I saw that question come up and thought nothing of this, just assumed it was ok to use. Conclusion: OP's code is perfectly valid.

Comment: I think this code is fine. The problem that is prevented by the specification that @chris quoted is the *construction* of that variable. *Allocation* is often done somewhere else. `goto`s are pretty useless if you can't jump over side-effects. If a constructor is not called, that is bad -- OTOH you have to make sure yourself the objects are in the states *you* require them to be in when you jump to a certain part of the code.

Comment: @chris, if you would like, you should formulate an answer based on these comments and we can move on.

Comment: @RSahu, I think the combination of given links explains it pretty well, but I'm having a hard time with a decision of closing it as a single one, especially when two of the better answers are the second answers in their corresponding questions.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, your comment itself is a duplicate of the answer below:-P

Comment: it autogenerates that comment when you flag article as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found another question with close answer:

[Why is it OK to jump into the scope of an object of scalar type w/o an initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529383/why-is-it-ok-to-jump-into-the-scope-of-an-object-of-scalar-type-w-o-an-initializ)

To summarize and answer the questions:

1. The `goto` is a run-time thing. Definition still happens;
2. Yes it is compiled.
3. No it is not executed.
4. Definition happens despite the part skipped by `goto`.